# Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined in main.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                     
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top //HERE THE ERROR
    }, 500);
    return false;
}); 
$("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 440,
       play: {
                 active: true,
                 auto: true,
                 interval: 9000,
                 swap: true
               }
      });            
});
```

gives me the error that i write in the title 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

This happen only when a try to do a particular action. This action is voting photo from a wordpress plugin: photo contest wordpress plugin.

So how can i stop that line of code if substr(1) is undefined?
I search problems like this on google but nothing works. 
If i comment that line voting photo start to work but other function stops.

Comment: well make sure the anchor has an href before attaching the event

Comment: `So how can i stop that line of code if substr(1) is undefined?` It's not the `substr` that is undefined, it's the string that you are calling substr upon that is undefined. You could do a null/undefined check before executing this action

Comment: `$.attr(this, 'href')` is not a valid syntax.  See https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you're using `.attr` incorrectly, but you also have stuff so chained together that when things go wrong it may be unclear exactly where things are messing up. Here's your code cleaned up a bit to warn as soon as potential issue comes up (it's probably overkill, but good for learning):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
        var $a = $(this),
            href = $a.attr("href");

        if (href && href.length > 1) {
            var sel = '[name="' + href.substr(1) + '"]',
                $el = $(sel);
            if ($el) {
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $el.offset().top
                }, 500);
            } else {
                console.warn("Could not find:", sel);
            }
        } else {
            console.warn("Clicked but no href found");
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 440,
        play: {
            active: true,
            auto: true,
            interval: 9000,
            swap: true
        }
    });
});
```